# Migrate CoreData/sqlite records into new version (from Library to Documens folder)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I made complete rewrite of my app previously developed by 3rd party. They used Magical Record for CoreData and I have located their appname.sqlite file on simulator in /Library/Application Support/AppName/ folder.

I am still learning CoreData and use CoreData app template from Xcode and my sqlite sits in /Documents/ folder. Can someone please advise the code to open the old store so I can perform migration? Thank you.

Original code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [MagicalRecordHelpers setupCoreDataStack];
    .....
    return YES;
}
```

MagicalRecord:

```
+ (void) setupCoreDataStack
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    [NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:context];
}


+ (void) MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator];
    if ([MagicalRecordHelpers isICloudEnabled]) 
    {
        [defaultManageObjectContext_ MR_stopObservingiCloudChangesInCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    MR_RETAIN(moc);
    MR_RELEASE(defaultManageObjectContext_);

    defaultManageObjectContext_ = moc;

    if ([MagicalRecordHelpers isICloudEnabled]) 
    {
        [defaultManageObjectContext_ MR_observeiCloudChangesInCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
}


+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) MR_defaultStoreCoordinator
{
    if (defaultCoordinator_ == nil && [MagicalRecordHelpers shouldAutoCreateDefaultPersistentStoreCoordinator])
    {
        [self MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:[self MR_newPersistentStoreCoordinator]];
    }
    return defaultCoordinator_;
}


+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *) MR_newPersistentStoreCoordinator
{
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self MR_coordinatorWithSqliteStoreNamed:[MagicalRecordHelpers defaultStoreName]];
    MR_RETAIN(coordinator);
    return coordinator;
}

+ (NSString *) defaultStoreName;
{
    NSString *defaultName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:(id)kCFBundleNameKey];
    if (defaultName == nil)
    {
        defaultName = kMagicalRecordDefaultStoreFileName;
    }
    if (![defaultName hasSuffix:@"sqlite"]) 
    {
        defaultName = [defaultName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
    }

    return defaultName;
}
```

EDIT:

Code to overtake the file:

```
- (void)migrateVersion1
{
    NSURL *version1URL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bundlename/Bundlename.sqlite"];

    NSManagedObjectModel *version1Model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:version1URL];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *version1PCS;
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (version1Model != nil) {
    version1PCS = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:version1Model];
    }

    if (![version1PCS addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:version1URL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // handle error
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *version1Context;
    if (version1PCS != nil) {
    version1Context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [version1Context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:version1PCS];
    }

    // start parsing
}
```

Comment: Did you actually change the data model, or just the location you want to save the file at? Why move it to Documents folder?

Comment: I did change the model, but the model itself is not complex. I have extended it as well, so the best for me would be to read the old records and store it into my new model on first launch and then forget the old. I used xcode template for coredata when creating new project and the template stores it in the documents folder.

Comment: Did you use a versioned Managed Object Model? I hope you did, because then you could have just used Auto-migration. IIRC, modern Xcode creates version models be default so it could just be a case of creating a new version and allowing auto-migration.

Comment: Appologies, but I am still learning CoreData and my conclusion was that I want to avoid using MagicalRecord in the first place. So at this stage I would just need an advice how to connect to the original sqlite and parse it (I know how to fetch and parse it). If there are steps I need to do with the model, please advise as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:
Copy/move the existing core data model into your new XCode project (You appear to be starting from scratch again). Select the model and then pick Editor-->New Version. Click on the model again and then in the right hand menu, select the new model version. Make the *minor* changes you need to the data model. The app should auto upgrade the datamodel for you.

Method 2:
Copy/move the existing core data model into your new XCode project. Write a quick parse that will fetch all the objects in the previous model, and create them in your new model. Be sure that you don't mix your MOC's.

Method 3 (Insanity.gif):
If you don't have access to the source code for the previous version... you're gonna have a bad time. It is possible to reverse engineer a core data sqlite file, but know that Apple may change how it works at any time. If you look at the tables you'll see `Z[name-of-object]` tables `ZFOO`, `ZBAR` etc... One to One relationships are easily grokked via the columns in the tables, `Z[relationship-name]` such as `ZMANAGER`, `ZADDRESS` etc. One/Many-to-Many will have a table `Z_[number-from-metadata-for-obj1][name-of-obj-2]` e.g. `Z_3ADDRESS` . The numbers that relate to the alphabetical order of the first object compared to all the objects in the db. Yeah. `Z_PK` is the primary key for each table, and used as reference in all relationship mappings. `Z_PrimaryKey` is your guide for debugging To-many relationships, specifically the `Z_ENT` column.

Good Luck

Comment: I do have the original source and so I go for method 2. Can you please suggest code to open the original sqlite and get context from it? I am apparently struggling with basics. I have tried to apply the model/psc/context code from my current appDelegate, but the code is crashing when I try to init the model from the URL. I can post the code if I find how to edit my original quesiton.

Comment: I made it working on the end. The second line of my migrate method is wrong. I should have used model URL like: NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"OriginalDataModelName" withExtension:@"momd"]; and then init model with content of this ModelURL, not the sqlite file obviously. After this it works like a charm. Many thanks to all!